# Using GSAP to create horizontal scroll section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap, scrolltrigger

I'm trying to achieve a `section` which, when in view, becomes a horizontal scroller until the items in the scroller (in my case, images) are finished, at which point, it becomes a vertical scroller again.

I've seen and adapted my approach on the following demos:

- [Horizontal Scroll with GSAP](https://codepen.io/oldskool123/pen/mdrrbyo)
- [ScrollTrigger - Horizontal Scrolling](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24309-scrolltrigger-horizontal-scrolling/)

The asthetic I'm trying to achieve is to show two images by default, then scroll to see rest. See below for a mockup:

[image]

Here is my current approach:

```js
$(function() {

  let scroll_tl = gsap.timeline({
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: '.horizontalScroller__images',
      start: "top center",
      // pin: true,
      scrub: true,
      end: "+=300",
      // markers: true,
    }
  });

  var images = document.querySelectorAll('.horizontalScroller__item');

  scroll_tl.to('.horizontalScroller__intro', {
    duration: 1,
    ease: "slow"
  });

  scroll_tl.to(images, {
    xPercent: -85 * (images.length - 1),
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: ".horizontalScroller__images",
      start: "center center",
      pin: true,
      // horizontal: true,
      // pinSpacing:false,
      markers: true,
      scrub: 1,
      snap: 1 / (images.length - 1),
      // end: () => `+=4320`
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.spacer{
  height: 300vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

.horizontalScroller {
  padding: 114px 0 80px 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #5d209f;
}
.horizontalScroller__intro {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.horizontalScroller__header {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.horizontalScroller__images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.horizontalScroller__scroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 60px 0;
}
/* .horizontalScroller__item {
  width: 25vw;
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="spacer"> Scroll down </div>

<section class="horizontalScroller">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-xl-6">
        <div class="horizontalScroller__intro">
          <h2 class="horizontalScroller__header">This is the header</h2>
          <p class="horizontalScroller__standfirst mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="horizontalScroller__scroll">

    <div class="horizontalScroller__images" id="horizontal-scroll">
      <div class="horizontalScroller__item">
        <img class="horizontalScroller__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontalScroller__item">
        <img class="horizontalScroller__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontalScroller__item">
        <img class="horizontalScroller__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontalScroller__item">
        <img class="horizontalScroller__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

In my above demo, you can see that when scrolling in that section, the images move down (not intended) and then they start moving towards the left (whereas the horizontal scroll should move to the right).

Also, to show the two cards initially, I've tried to set a `width` to the `.horizontalScroller__item`, but it just messes it up even more.

Unsure why my code is performing the way it is, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use top most parent container `horizontalScroller`, that is spanning entire viewport height as a scrollTrigger:

```js
$(function() {
  let images = gsap.utils.toArray(".horizontalScroller__item");

  gsap.to(images, {
    xPercent: -100 * (images.length - 1),
    ease: "none",
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: ".horizontalScroller",
      pin: true,
      scrub: 1,
      snap: 1 / (images.length - 1),
      end: () => "+=" + document.querySelector(".horizontalScroller__images").offsetWidth
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.spacer {
  height: 300vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

.horizontalScroller {
  padding: 2rem 0 1rem 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #5d209f;
}

.horizontalScroller__intro {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.horizontalScroller__header {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.horizontalScroller__scroll {
  height: 70%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.horizontalScroller__images {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.horizontalScroller__item {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.horizontalScroller__image {
  width: 70%;
  object-fit: fill;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.copyrights {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="spacer"> Scroll down </div>

<section class="horizontalScroller">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-xl-6">
        <div class="horizontalScroller__intro">
          <h2 class="horizontalScroller__header">This is the header</h2>
          <p class="horizontalScroller__standfirst mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="horizontalScroller__scroll">

    <div class="horizontalScroller__images" id="horizontal-scroll">
      <div class="horizontalScroller__item">
        <img class="horizontalScroller__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontalScroller__item">
        <img class="horizontalScroller__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontalScroller__item">
        <img class="horizontalScroller__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontalScroller__item">
        <img class="horizontalScroller__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontalScroller__item">
        <img class="horizontalScroller__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontalScroller__item">
        <img class="horizontalScroller__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
<div class="copyrights">Copyrights</div>
```